# Is it possible to post to a Facebook user wall as an application or page using the Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to find a way to post to a user's wall and have it appear as coming from another Facebook page (which they do NOT have ownership of) or application (that they have granted extended permissions to). I know that when you post to a wall from an application without specifying the from attribute, it will show "via x" where x is the application name - that is NOT what I am trying to do.

Alternatively, it could show up in a user's news feed, but the message would have to be specific to that user which I don't think is possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can read everything you need to know in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts). You just need to issue a HTTP POST request to the graph path /PROFILE_ID/feed and provide all required fields.

**Edit_:** If you want to post on the App's Wall as the App, use the App's ID as PROFILE_ID and use the access token of your app (not the user access token). If you want to post on the App's wall as the use, use the user access token.

Comment: Thanks Björn - I did try this, but no matter what I tried, it always posted as the user of the application, not the application itself. I tried several variations of from attribute values too but none worked. I understand the mechanics of POSTing to the post graph API, I just don't know which specific options will make it appear from the application rather than the user. Can you provide guidance on that?

Comment: So you want to post to the App's wall and not to the User's Wall?

Comment: No, sorry - I want to post to a user's wall, but have it appear as the application having posted it.

Comment: Than my initial solution is correct, but you need the users permission to perform this action (publish_stream to name it)

Comment: This isn't working for me. When I post to /user_id/feed, the message shows up on the wall but as the user. For example:

{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1000032386xxxxx_112468602xxxxxx", 
      "from": {
        "name": "Will Amcbchfajifc Occhinostein", 
        "id": "1000032386xxxxx"
      }, 
      "message": "test", 
       ...

Is the resulting wall post. The name in the from object is the test user name, NOT the application name. The from needs to be the application name. Am I missing something?

Comment: What happens when you post to /user_id/feed and use your application access_token and not the user access token?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5878/discussion-between-chris-hart-and-bjorn-kaiser)